# Castle Monorail Databinding in an Action

Tags: production-environment, castle, castle-monorail

We have an issue whereby we have a download link on our website (running Castle Monorail) that downloads some data as a CSV. The Action method is as follows:

```
public void TransactionReportSearch([DataBind("searchParameters", Validate = true)]TransactionSearchParameters searchParameters, int page,
                                        bool showStatistics)
```

Strangely enough, the databinding is working on our test environment but does not work on our live environment. We have discovered that the DataBindAttribute is working when we are doing a HTTP POST but it doesn't seem to be working on a HTTP GET. This of course could be a red herring as it is working on the test environment.

I suspect this could be a configuration issue. What should I check between the test and live environment to ensure that Castle Monorail databinding in the Action is configured correctly?

Comment: are you binding against Form? or QueryString?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test but can you try Databind's From=ParamStore.Params option. It says "From QueryString, Form and Environment variables.".